# ffmpeg: a way to write to a temp file and rename when finished writing?

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, file-watcher, ffmpeg-python

i am using ffmpeg to split a video into frames and wondering if there any flags i can set so that ffmpeg will start writing the frame to a file and only rename it when its finished writing to it.

for context this is the current ffmpeg command im using:

ffmpeg -loglevel 8 -ss <start_time> -to <end_time> -copyts -i <input_file_path> -vf <vf_params> -vsync passthrough -compression_level 1 -frame_pts true -sws_flags lanczos <output_pattern>

for further context, i am asking since i have set up a watcher on the directory ffmpeg writes to but i dont want to do anything with the file until its been fully written to and closed.

i also dont want to rename every file when the full ffmpeg operation has completed, since it would defeat the purpose of my watcher, but rather as soon as 1 file has been fully written to, rename it.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your watcher not able to know when a file is closed?